# How to do bluetooth pairing at factory time

Tags: bluetooth, cryptography, bluetooth-lowenergy, pki, pairing

I have some Bluetooth LE **v4.2** beacons that I will **connect ONLY** with **known devices** that we may call "readers". The beacons are program and installed by me. I consume the data and I sell the service.

I want to use a **hard-coded shared secret** to realize the pairing or communication. My primary concern is that only a known and authenticated device SHALL be able to send data (with integrity protection).

**What would be my best option ?**

A few previsions :

- We are talking about 1000s of devices, and more will join the network every day.
- I am already doing advertisement filter, etc. I only connect to devices with my vendor id.
- Replacement if preferable to any kind of lack of security in the authentication, my added value is the trust in data.
- I have an OTA update system for all the devices.

Interesting documentation I found about Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) security :

- [NIST Guide to Bluetooth Security](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-121r2.pdf)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An answer to my question on the [Nordicsemi devzone](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/30663/how-to-setup-pre-bonded-link-pairing-at-factory-time) gave me some hints. Find below the answers I was looking for. I hope that will help.

## Mode 1 Level 4 (encryption) vs Mode 2 Level 2 (signing)

**Resources** :

- [Dev zone semi question](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/30663/how-to-setup-pre-bonded-link-pairing-at-factory-time?ReplySortBy=CreatedDate&ReplySortOrder=Ascending)

> Forget about CSRK. It's a bad idea that almost no BLE stacks support. One reason is that it only supports Write Without Response in one direction. Another is that you need to keep a write counter stored in flash. A third is that a MITM could potentially delay a message for an arbitrary time and doesn't need an active connection during this time. It has no benefits at all compared to the normal AES-CCM except that CCM takes 2.5 round trips to set up for BLE.

## How to ensure secure encryption with a pre-shared secret

**Resources** :

- [Dev zone semi question](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/30663/how-to-setup-pre-bonded-link-pairing-at-factory-time?ReplySortBy=CreatedDate&ReplySortOrder=Ascending)
- [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48859717/how-to-do-bluetooth-pairing-at-factory-time/48870683?noredirect=1)
- [Dev zone semi : Pre-shared key = OOB](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/30793/what-could-be-better-for-security-encryption-and-authentication-passkey-vs-pki/122101)
- [Dev zone semi : OOB LESC vs Legacy](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/14391/passing-out-of-band-key-to-peer-manager)

### Do we need pairing ?

No pairing :

> If you remove the pairing step from BLE security you basically just have AES-CCM with pre-shared keys, where each connection has an own key derived from the shared key and a nonce from each side. LESC is about the pairing step which you want to remove, so that doesn't apply in that case.

Vs Out Of Band (OOB) :

> A pre-shared key is an example of OOB (Out of band) pairing. That might sound a bit strange, but essentially you are using the production setup in your factory as the medium to share keys. You do not want to have the LTK or any BLE bonding data pre-shared, but rather just a key at some location in flash which can be used in a regular OOB pairing.

Preferred solution is Out of band pairing.

### LESC with pre-shared passkey vs OOB with pre-shared key ?

**Resources** :

- [Dev zone semi : Pre-shared key](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/14743/ble-minimal-modifications-to-use-pre-shared-key-auth-and-encryption)

> The first time you connect you should authenticate the other device, and you can do this by using your pre-shared key when you bond. You can bond by using Passkey Entry or OOB. The key used with Passkey Entry is short, so I would recommend using a 128-bit key with OOB, this is much more secure.

### Out of band LESC Vs Out Of Band Legacy

> Both LESC and Legacy end up with 128-bit encryption keys, and these are equally secure. The power consumption will be the same after pairing is done. LESC uses a more complex algorithm so it will use more power during the pairing process. The difference is in the key generation algorithm. It depends on what kind of attacks you want to protect against. If you do OOB with legacy and you are sure that the attacker can't get the OOB data, you are secure. If the attacker can get this data, you should go for LESC. What kind of central device are you connecting to? Does it support OOB and/or LESC?

In fact LESC out of band with pre-shared key is quite complicated to archive because of the calculation of the oob payload is supposed to be a random number signed with private key, and this mechanism is implemented in the softdevice but not accessible. Thus we could either re-invent the wheel, or just decide that this computation is useless as evedrop of out-of-band is just impossible with pre-shared key. Also, LESC oob pairing is more calculation intensive for no benefits.

### Out of band Legacy

For more detailed explanations of Out of band Legacy pairing, see [bluetooth.com](https://blog.bluetooth.com/bluetooth-pairing-part-5-legacy-pairing-out-of-band).

## Temporary key calculation

A master key will be included in the new FW release code (that's probably my major weakness, but I cannot do much about it). I will use [legacy Out Of Band pairing](http://blog.bluetooth.com/bluetooth-pairing-part-5-legacy-pairing-out-of-band). The Temporary Key (TK), used for paring communication encryption, will be derivated from the master key using generation function fc (inspired by the f5 function described in the Bluetooth specification).

The definition of this key generation function fc makes use of the MAC function AES-CMACT with a 128-bit key T.

The input of the function are:

- M is 128 bits
- A1 is 56 bits
- A2 is 56 bits

The string “******” is mapped into keyID using extended ASCII as follows:

- *keyID = 0xXXXXXXXXXXXX*

The output of the key generation function fc is as follows:

- *fc(M, A1, A2) = AES-CMAC<sub>M</sub>(keyID || 0x00 || A1 || A2 || Length = 128)*

The TK is calculated as:

- *TK = fc(Master key, DB_ADDR_master, DB_ADDR_slave)*

Comment: Please bring the key points of that link into your answer. Links tend to go dead, leaving the "answer" frustrating to people.

Comment: Specification wasn't enough to answer the questions. I edited my answer to explain per subject what I finally chose to do, and why.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn’t pair in factory, but instead add other programmatically controlled mechanisms in the FW. I’m thinking bondable  LE links, whitelisted MAC-addresses (as long as we’re not talking about random/obfuscated addresses).

If you have access to the chip/design in production, you could let the production test station use wired/wireless available interface and add the whitelisted MAC addresses in there...?

Or, use Vendor-specific data in the BLE advertisements data and add X identification bytes that you filter on in the LE central.

Or, use groups of custom Service UUIDs and add to the adv data, allowing centrals to filter on that.

Etc etc — the point is; my experience of setting production pre-paired stuff has always ended up in chaos, and there should *always* be a mechanism to clear your pairing and manually setup thing as you, or your customer, want. How else would you deal with replacements, upgrades etc and sudden implicit or explicit breaking changes — always design things so that there’s a way to get thing up and running from scratch again. Depending on the product, that might be using a Config tool from PC, or Admin-mode from your phone/app, or the like — but don’t rely on production-defined pairings.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I added precision to my initial question.

**Questions :**
- What is bondable LE Links ?
- Tell me if I am wrong, but I guess MAC-addresses can be easily changed and I have no insurance that I am connecting to a trusted device (which is my only concern), even if it advertise a known address.

Comment: @4nti7rust bonded links in LE is similar to pairings in classic Bluetooth. Since you’re going for SC, bonded LE is implicit. The alternative is LE peripherals advertising and allowing everyone to find and connect to you.

Comment: @4nti7rust thx for the updated question and details. So it’s a controlled system setup by you, not the customer. The LE central is a phone/app/gadget? How’s the quantifications and relations? Android/iOS? One LE central, or n many different units that should be allowed to connect? If one, then a) all LE peripherals come from factory, setup by you and will automatically advertise in bondable state. Once bonded they automatically recent any further bonding and then you’re done. But you’d need a fallback/factory-default mechanism to allow for re-configuration I guess.

Comment: There are many ways to restrict connectivity, but all I’m saying is that do NOT try to hard code the pairing data in production. Been there. Thought it would be a great solution. Then reality came ;)

Comment: No android/iOS, only micro-controllers, on both sides (with code-dumping protection). Many beacons that will connects with multiple centrals during they life. They can all be setup in factory by me. You understand it right, I want to advertise in a bondable state, how can I do that? Why would I need a fallback ?

Comment: What was the issues with pairing data in production ?

Comment: @4nti7rust all chips I’ve worked with has had a max nbr of paired link keys and/or whitelisted bonded LE centrals. Typically 8. If you plan to have more centrals and peripherals, you might get into problems.

Comment: If you have a dynamic list of trusted MAC addresses in your peripherals, you could simply have a USB/UART wired access to the peripherals (for security reasons only) where you could use a Config app on your PC and have a simple client running to program the peripherals one by one. Then, the peripherals only allow those LE centrals to connect. You could have a challenge/response thing as part of the header in the logical protocol you use via the characteristics too, using the MAC address of the central/peripheral as part of the challenge/response algorithm.

Comment: @4nti7rust that way you’d have some level of protection for fraud LE centrals spoofing their MAC address to try to get entry in your system; all LE centrals that can’t answer the challenge bytes sent by the peripheral will be automatically disconnected. And if the MAC address of both sides are involved, you’ll have different responses and challenges for each pair of peripheral/central.

Comment: @4nti7rust I’ve never tried production pairing for LE, but I tried for classic pairings to get a True-Wireless pair of earbuds be “hard coded” to each other. And things worked, sure, but OTA upgrades could accidentally break that contract (unintentionally but still), and more over we had problems with substitutes of bad earbuds as customers didn’t want a replacement kit with 2 buds, only 1 which perhaps they lost or destroyed by accident.